# Joomla component - list view admin page - search is not working

Tags: joomla, components

In my joomla 3.x component I have list view admin page, where I added some search tools:

```
        <div class="filter-search btn-group pull-left">
            <label for="filter_search" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER');?></label>
            <input type="text" name="filter_search" id="filter_search" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER'); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->state->get('filter.search')); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group pull-left">
            <button class="btn hasTooltip" type="submit" title="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT'); ?>"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            <button class="btn hasTooltip" id="clear-search-button" type="button" title="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR'); ?>"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
        </div>
```

but obviously it's not working. How and where should I add the support for that search? I suppose I should add some actions to the model?

I want the search to be working only on some (2 out of 7) columns of my datatable.

**UPDATE:**

In my model's file in `populateState` method I have:

```
    // Load the filter state.
    $search = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
    $this->setState('filter.search', $search);
```

and in `getListQuery` method:

```
    // Filter by search in title
    $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
    if (!empty($search)) {
        if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
            $query->where('a.email = ' . $search );
        } else {
            $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');

        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

OK, I managed to make the search work for me. I don't know why some of default joomla syntax broke my search.

Effectively, commenting out some elements from `getListQuery` in my model file and adding proper `where` clause did the trick:

```
    // Filter by search in title
    $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
    if (!empty($search)) {
        //if (stripos($search, 'email:') === 0) {
            $query->where('a.email LIKE "%' . $search .'%" OR a.imie LIKE "%'.$search.'%"' );
//            } else {
//                $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
//                
//            }
    }
```

So I'm upholding my bounty to the one that would explain why I had to comment these sections from `getListQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a list view in joomla. The main content that populates the list comes from the corresponding model file.

If it is a standard Joomla component, there will be a function by the name getListQuery() in it.

Go ahead and add the code over there. For Example:

```
$search = $this->getState('filter.search');
        if (!empty($search)) {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
                $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
            } else {
                $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
//The previous line or directly $query->where('somecolumn like ' . $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%'));



            }
        }
```

Also add this in the populateState

```
// Load the filter state.
        $search = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
        $this->setState('filter.search', $search);
```

This will set the variables in state.
Just do this and you are done.

**UPDATE:**
The answer should be

```
$search = $this->getState('filter.search');
    if (!empty($search)) {
        if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
            $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
        } else {
            $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
    $query->where('a.email LIKE ' . $search .' OR a.imie LIKE '.$search );


        }
    }
```

**Explanation:**

Normally the "Search" is considered to be the common search field for a list view. Normally, it works for most of the columns, so instead of creating separate search boxes for all, it is recommended to keep just a single one with a common purpose of searching all columns.

Now, it also depends on what the user would like to be searched. So by default Joomla users use the above code.

In this if "id:3" is searched, it will immediately go in the if part since  "id:" is mentioned, so the if part becomes true and it will then search by id (which will return row with id 3). In normal cases, it would automatically go to the else part.

Finally, these are just standard practices. Even if you write only the condition, the code would work. The choice is yours.

Comment: Please see my update - I already had it and still not working.

Comment: Then do this. After `$search = $this->getState('filter.search');` do this `var_dump($search);exit`. Just let me know if this returns anything other than null. While you are at it, just check if there are 2 fields with name "filter_search" in your form.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, but there's still a bounty - please see my edit.

Comment: Also the piece of code `$query->where('a.email = ' . $search );` should be in the else part

Comment: Nice, but the if part is to allow search by id and the else part is for fields other than id. If you search  "id:1" it will return the row with id 1, the else part handles all the other cases. It is advisable to write the code in else part as mentioned previously in the code comment in my "answer"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set form 'id' and 'name'  "adminForm" in component view file.
It will resolve the issue.

For Example:

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_test&view=test" method="post" id="adminForm" name="adminForm">
.....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok in the view you need something like that :
- update the form in you view to post to the controller
- update the controller to handle the post and display the results

**On the View :**

```php
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_test&view=search'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">

    <div class="filter-search btn-group pull-left">
        <label for="filter_search" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER');?></label>
        <input type="text" name="filter_search" id="filter_search" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER'); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->state->get('filter.search')); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER'); ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group pull-left">
        <button class="btn hasTooltip" type="submit" title="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT'); ?>"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
        <button class="btn hasTooltip" id="clear-search-button" type="button" title="<?php echo JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR'); ?>"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search"/>
</form>
```

So actually now when you are submitting  you are posting to the controller `TestController` calling the method `search` .

The 2 hidden fields are making this actually.

**On the Controller :**

Now on `components/com_test/controller.php` you can add the `search` method.

```php
class TestController extends JControllerLegacy 
{
    /**
     * Other methods here 
     *    .
     *    .
     *    .
     */

    /**
     * Pseudo code for search
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // get the data posted
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $jform  = $jinput->post->get('jform', null, null);

        // make a query in the db
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query
            ->select($db->quoteName(array('col_2', 'col_7')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__your_table'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('filter_search') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($jform['filter_search']))

        // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
        $db->setQuery($query);

        // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();

        // send the result to a view 
        $view   = $this->getView('search', 'html'); //get the view
        $view->assignRef('data', $results); // assign data from the model
        $view->display(); // display the view

        return $this;
    }
```

As you can see here there are 3 main points:

- get the data posted
- make a query in the db
- send the result to a view

The view in this eg it would be in `components/com_test/views/search/view.html.php`.

Comment: How can I add another `<form>` tag if I'm already operating inside other view? changing the action view for my form would break my other functionality, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well in the same page you can have more than one Form.  Actually you can have as much as you want, just close one before to start the other.  Consider that you have to modify the action according to your case.